# SSD1306 128x32 OLED change I2C address

Tags: arduino, i2c, oled, ssd1306

Hey all I've been looking for any information that would allow me to change the I2C address for the 0.91" OLED 128x32 module:

[image]

So far I have only found mention of the I2c address change [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/AskElectronics/comments/19fg6sg/how_do_i_change_the_address_of_this_i2c_oled/) but that does not seem to be a label on the back of my module (D/C#)?

Here is the [datasheet](https://www.digikey.com/htmldatasheets/production/2047793/0/0/1/ssd1306.html) and I can not seem to find anything on changing the address but that post above mentioned page 15 of the datasheet:

[image]

But again, those label names do not match up with my module. I have 3 of these I need to hookup to my Arduino Pro Micro so I know for certain they will all be the same I2C address. Trying to accomplish this without the need to get a I2c multiplexer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try removing one of the resistors at a time to see if the address changes. The problem is that if one of those resistors does set the SA0 pin to low or high, removing the resistor leaves the SA0 pin floating, as there is no mention of the chip having internal pull-ups or pull-downs on it, so the SA0 pin has to be pulled to opposite state to what it was.

But if there is no documentation of what you bought, you cannot know if there even is a way to change the address.

The address pin of the chip could be fixed and unchangeable on the PCB.

However, it might be irrelevant to be able to change the address.

As there is only one address pin, you can have only two displays on same bus segment.

So you need a bus mux for three displays or more than one I2C bus for up to 4 displays.

However, if one of the pins is SA0, you can use MCU IO pins to control SA0 pin on each or one display, so just set which two displays are at same address and which one display is at unique address to access it.